# Getting what has changed in ContentObserver

Tags: android, contentobserver

I want to know if the volume has changed. Reading other post I found this code to register a ContentObserver and get an event when something changes. 
My problem is that I don't know how to know what has changed. I mean, I get an OnReceive() but how can I get the extra information (what volume key was pressed, for example).

I also get a lot of unneeded events, for example, clicking on the "Menu" button triggers this event too, but nothing has changed (yet).

This is my code.

Thank you

```
public class clsSettingsContentObserver extends ContentObserver
{
   public Context Contexto=null; //This is for displaying Toasts

   public clsSettingsContentObserver(Handler handler)
   {  super(handler);
   } 


   @Override public boolean deliverSelfNotifications()
   {
      return super.deliverSelfNotifications(); 
   }


   @Override public void onChange(boolean selfChange)
   {  super.onChange(selfChange);

      //How do I get more info here?????
      ShowToast("Settings change detected");    
   }


   private void ShowToast(String strMensaje)
   {  Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(Contexto, strMensaje, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
      toast1.show();   
   };

}
```

And this is how I register it:

```
clsSettingsContentObserver oSettingsContentObserver = new clsSettingsContentObserver( new Handler() );
oSettingsContentObserver.Contexto = this; //This is for displaying Toasts
getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(
            android.provider.Settings.System.CONTENT_URI,
            true, 
            oSettingsContentObserver);
```

Answer (score 1):

Register the content observer using

```
getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(
        android.provider.Settings.System.CONTENT_URI,
        false, 
        oSettingsContentObserver);
```

This will stop unwanted notifications from descendants of the database. See [public final void registerContentObserver (Uri uri, boolean notifyForDescendents, ContentObserver observer)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#registerContentObserver%28android.net.Uri,%20boolean,%20android.database.ContentObserver%29) for more details

Answer (score 0):

For the purpose you can also use a broadcast receiver:

Register this in Manifest:

```
<receiver android:name="MyClass" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.media.VOLUME_CHANGED_ACTION" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Use this code in MyClass.java:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Var_Volume_Value = (Integer) intent.getExtras().get("android.media.EXTRA_VOLUME_STREAM_VALUE");
}
```